# React + redux containers

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to figure out which is the best way to implement React + redux containers.
I have two containers, for ex: "parent" and "child" and both are connected to redux store, is this a good way? Or I should put only stateless dumb components inside containers which have all actions and every necessary functions.

I am building this kind of architecture : "main page container" -> "child containers (like: sidebar or sth)" -> "sidebars' child container (and some of them has dumb child components, some of them not)" - (all containers are connected to redux). Am I building very wrong way? please give me suggestions, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this project, it's talk about how to structure your react redux project, https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

Comment: thanks, someone finally wrote me something ^^, yes I saw this template but I didn't want to use it so I am building everything on my own and I am almost finished my structure but now my question is how bad is to put react+redux container inside another react+redux container, is it will be hard to manage after a while :? I am not sure so that was the reason why I asked this question.

Comment: @vano it's not a wrong way, it just depends on the complexity of your nested components is, for example, you have nested components like<FirstLayer>,  <SecondLayer>, <ThirdLayer> <FourthLayer>, in this case, instead of passing all the dispatch action and props from First to Fourth, it will be better to just connect Fourth with redux. or using React 16.4+ context API, in fact, the redux it's build based on the context. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: thank you for your advice ^_^ I will look into react context